# Manually delete ImageResizer Cache Folder

Tags: imageresizer

is it safe to manually delete the Imageresizer.net diskcache folder. I have Autoclean enabled but the folder is way to large, so is it safe to delete all content?

Answer (score 0):

It is safe to manually delete the cache folder, but keep in mind that some files may be locked if the app is running.

You should migrate to the replacement product, [Imageflow Server](https://github.com/imazen/imageflow-dotnet-server), to use the newer version of disk caching (HybridCache). It uses a write-ahead-log to track created files and has accurate size utilization accounting so your cache folder won't grow beyond the size limit you specify.

I'm the author of both libraries.